# AOT - Function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

Here's Angular 2 code I use for state in my small app (thanks to Victor Savkin articles):

```
const initState = new OpaqueToken("initState");
export const dispatcher = new OpaqueToken("dispatcher");
export const state = new OpaqueToken("state");

const dispValue = new Subject<Action>();
const initStateValue = { subscribers: [], news: [] };

export const stateAndDispatcher = [
    {
        provide: initState,
        useValue: initStateValue
    },
    {
        provide: dispatcher,
        useValue: dispValue
    },
    {
        provide: state,
        useFactory: stateFn,
        deps: [initState, dispatcher]
    }
];
```

It all works until I compile it with AOT. My repo is based on @qdouble great repo - https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/.

AOT compilation throws this error:

> > Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol stateAndDispatcher

Could someone help fixing this? I don't get the reason for this error in my case.

**Update** - here's stateFn (imported from another file):

```
export function stateFn(initState: AppState, actions: Observable<Action>): Observable<AppState> {
    const appStateObs: Observable<AppState> = subscribers(initState.subscribers, actions)
        .zip(processNews(initState.news, actions))
        .map(s => ({ subscribers: s[0], news: s[1] }));
    return wrapIntoBehavior(initState, appStateObs);
}
```

Comment: Presumably it's struggling with `stateFn`, that's the one with a function call.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - added stateFn. Still no idea how to fix this...

Answer (score 3):

All methods used for the providers need to be exported and have to be "regular" functions.
So the arrow function in your `map` needs to be changed to a regular function which is exported + `wrapIntoBehaviour` needs to be exported.
I am not sure how your `processNews` method looks, but that would have to be exported as well.